# openssl version through _ssl.pyd file

Tags: python, executable, pyopenssl

I have a compiled python executable, and the python files for libraries along with it. It includes the _ssl.pyd file also.

Is there a way to find out the version of openssl with which the executable was compiled?

Comment: https://pyopenssl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install.html#supported-openssl-versions ?

Comment: @simar, ok, so is `python -m OpenSSL.debug` supposed to be run in bash? It is giving me error, **No module ..** And anyways it would give me the current openssl version, not the version which that OS had when the compiled files were created.

Answer (score 0):

I have guess that pyopenssl just a pure python wrapper of builtin ssl module. If i am right then you get version

```
>>> import ssl
>>> ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION
```